# WordPress as GraphQL client

Tags: api

If I'm using WordPress as a front-end for GraphQL that's hosted on another back-end site, what is the best method/plugin I can use to send queries *from* WP *to* another server on the backend? If you search Google for **Wordpress GraphQL**, pretty much everything points to the [WPGraphQL](https://www.wpgraphql.com/) plugin. But that seems to be much more a framework for allowing WordPress to act as a GQL server, when what I want is a client.

Comment: What are you serving from GraphQL - the posts and pages, or just some data loaded into pages, or something else?

Comment: It's mainly for pushing data from a form I will host on WordPress to the backend in the form of GraphQL mutations. If the backend server responds with a 200 OK then WP will report that to the user and move on.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Have you found something to publish data from graphql to wordpress?